# Javascript: Iterate through ID -> cannot set property 'onclick' of null javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code a modal with a slideshow. It works fine for the first picture when I type '1' instead of 'i' in the for loop. When I use 'i' in the for loop I get the error message "cannot set property 'onclick' of null javascript"
I know that this is some very beginner stuff... but I'm sitting here now for hours to find a solution...
Thank you for your help!

```
window.onload = function() {
    var modal;
    var prefixModal = 'myModal';
    var img;
    var prefixmyImg = 'myImg';
    var modalImg;
    var prefixmodalImg = 'img';

    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      modal = document.getElementById(prefixModal + i);
      img = document.getElementById(prefixmyImg + i);
      modalImg = document.getElementById(prefixmodalImg + i);   
    }

     var closey = document.getElementsByClassName('close');

     img.onclick = function(){
     modal.style.display = "block";

     modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
     var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
     span.onclick = function() { 
     modal.style.display = "none";
     }
};

 .container_slideshow {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: block;
        height: 8rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .content_slideshow {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 40vw;
        background-color: darkgray;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
    }

    .content_slideshow:last-child {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 50%; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: scroll; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(57,61,69,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container_slideshow">
  <div class="content_slideshow">
    <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
    <img class="slider" id="myImg1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/SilburyHill_gobeirne.jpg/1200px-SilburyHill_gobeirne.jpg" alt="">
      <!-- The Modal -->
    <a class="close">
      <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img1">
        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="content_slideshow">
    <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
    <img class="slider" id="myImg2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/SilburyHill_gobeirne.jpg/1200px-SilburyHill_gobeirne.jpg" alt="">
      <!-- The Modal -->
    <a class="close">
      <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img2">
        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a very rough look I'd say the DOM node with id `"myModal0"` doesn't exist (which is most likely true for your other prefixes as well it just happens to be the first you try to get the DOM node of. 
Keep in mind that your loop starts at 0 not 1.

Also keep in mind that each node you are trying to assign must exist beforehand! So you either have to have each element in your html file or create them on the fly with JS.

If you wanted to start at 1 you could do:

```
for (let i=1; i<x; i++) {
    // do smth ...
}
```

Comment: when I change "myModal0", "myImg0" and "img0" it doesn't work

Comment: you know what a for loop does right? So in your loop you try to get the nodes of "myModal0", "myModal1", "myModal2", "myModal3", "myModal4", "myModal5". 
If any one of those does not exist it will throw a respective exception. Obviously that is true for all other nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  modal = document.getElementById(prefixModal + i);
  img = document.getElementById(prefixmyImg + i);
  modalImg = document.getElementById(prefixmodalImg + i); 

  // NOTE: put the code that does something IN HERE,
  // right now it's outside the loop
}
```

is iterating through all elements in the HTML document that have ids from "myModal0" through "myModal6", and the same for the other two prefixes "myImg" and "img".

I don't see all these elements in your HTML document.  I only see "myModal1" and "myModal2" (as well as elements 1 and 2 of "myImg" and "img".

It looks like you either need to reduce the size of the loop so it only iterates through the elements you actually have, or you need to fill out the rest of the HTML and put in the rest of the elements (all the way from 0 through (and including) 6.

Oh and there's another thing to remember here too, none of your actual code that is causing the error, is inside the loop.  All you do in the loop is setting the names of the variables.  So the later code is always using "myModal6", because that is the last thing the loop sets the names to.

Comment: i changed id like this:                                                                                   
for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  modal = document.getElementById(prefixModal + i);
  img = document.getElementById(prefixmyImg + i);
  modalImg = document.getElementById(prefixmodalImg + i);   
}                                                                                                                        and named the modals like: myModal0; myModal1                                                        now the second picture is opening but the first anymore

Comment: It's really this line where the error occurs:      img.onclick = function(){   
So I would put a console.log(img) right before it, to see is img is null.

Comment: After I did this, it logs myImg1 to the console but myImg0 not

Comment: More console logging could be helpful.  You can use it to make sure the names of the ids are what you think they are, and to determine whether getElementById returned null. Once one of the getElementById calls returns null instead of a real object, nothing is going to work well after that :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {`. The count starts from 0 and it will try to find a dom element with id `myModal6`.

Change the for loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```